# Where is the restore.js file located in Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox, tabs

I was using Mozilla Firefox and I had around 600 tabs on Onetab but suddenly all the tabs got lost and only tabs of yesterday were there. Through some links I found that backup is stored in `restore.js` file in Windows but where is this file in Ubuntu.

Comment: are you sure? I thought it was `sessionstore.js` for the current session when you close firefox and `recovery.js` when firefox crashed.

Answer (score 1):

in `~/.mozilla/firefox/your_profile/` you can find

- `sessionCheckpoints.json`
- `sessionstore.jsonlz4`

and the directory `sessionstore-backups`

Comment: I gave you +1 but couldn't get past the firefox folder.

Answer (score 1):

In more recent Ubuntu versions, Firefox is installed through a Snap, so the Firefox folder can be found in `~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox`.

Use the modification-time to find the folder corresponding to your Firefox session.

Then, the list of tabs is located in `$firefox_dir/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4`.

You can either copy this file into a new Firefox instance to read it, or decompress it by hand. To decompress it by hand, you'll need dejsonlz4 and jq.

```
$ ls -l ~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/
total 36K
drwx------ 18 sam sam 4.0K Nov 21 15:52  c6u2cvnb.defaultt
...

$ firefox_dir=~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/c6u2cvnb.defaultt

$ dejsonlz4 $firefox_dir/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4 firefox-recovery.json

$ jq --raw-output '.windows[].tabs[].entries | .[length-1].url' firefox-recovery.json
https://example.com/
https://example.com/
...
```